# Mini cart is displaying the configurable product image instead of simple product

Tags: configurable-product, magento-1, mini-cart

now, from similar questions on mag stack exch, I noticed that its possibly a problem with cartcontroller.php in which I have the following

```
        if (!$this->_getSession()->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
            if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                $message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()));
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
            }
            $this->_goBack();
        }
```

or there may be aproblem in checkout.xml with Itemrenderers in which i have the following

```
<reference name="right">
        <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the settings in admin section. Navigate to

> Admin > System > Configuration > Checkout > Shopping Cart >  Configurable Product Image as Product thumbnail itself

It'll render Child product image(Simple Product) in cart section.[image]

Comment: I have already done that, and simple product image displays in mini cart only after refresh of the page or after adding another product in mini cart, do you have any solutions for simple product image to display right after the product is added in mini cart?